# timezones in R: how to avoid ambiguous terms such as EST?

Tags: r, timezone, timestamp, time-series, posixct

I have a series of character timestamps in R. When I change their class to `POSIXct` using intuitive methods, R assigns the ambiguous timezone `EST`.

For example:

```
as.POSIXct("2012-08-06 15:32:00") 
as.POSIXct("2012-08-06 15:32:00", tz = "Australia/Brisbane") 
as.POSIXct("2012-08-06 15:32:00", tz = "")
```

all produce the same output on my two (Mac and Windows) boxes:

```
"2012-08-06 15:32:00 EST"
```

The problem here is `EST` could be any number of timezones: Eastern Standard Time in the USA, or Australian Eastern Standard Time, or another timezone in Canada (from `?timezone`):

> Beware that some of these designations may not be what you think: in
>   particular EST is a time zone used in Canada without daylight savings
>   time, and not EST5EDT nor (Australian) Eastern Standard Time.

There is a method to set the timezone which avoids this `EST` label. It is alluded to, but not fully explained in the R `?timezone` help. Setting x as the time of the Curiosity landing on Mars as reported by an [Australian news service](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2012-08-06/countdown-begins-to-dramatic-mars-landing/4178204):

```
x <- as.POSIXct("2012-08-06 15:32:00", tz = "Etc/GMT-10")
x
"2012-08-06 15:32:00 GMT-10"
```

And we can test that this is correct by converting it to a US timezone and checking with a [Californian news report](http://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/news/releases/2012/12-58AR.txt):

```
y <- format(x, tz = "America/Los_Angeles")
y
"2012-08-05 22:32:00"
```

If using this `Etc/GMT+n` or `Etc/GMT-n` notation, please beware of the following caveat from `?timezone` :

> Many systems support timezones of the form GMT+n and GMT-n, which are
>   at a fixed offset from UTC (hence no DST). Contrary to some usage (but
>   consistent with names such as PST8PDT), negative offsets are times
>   ahead of (east of) UTC, positive offsets are times behind (west of)
>   UTC.

Comment: Just found this [related question & answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8011954/1265353)

Comment: There is a SO 'best practices' for time/zone handling that may help with the conceptual side of things::  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532729/daylight-saving-time-and-timezone-best-practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 1st and 3rd lines in your first example produce the same output because `tz=""` is the default for `as.POSIXct`.  The second line is more interesting because the timezone is explicitly defined.

But note that `"EST"` is only how the timezone is printed by default.  The `tzone` attribute is still unambiguous.

```
R> x <- as.POSIXct("2012-08-06 15:32:00", tz="Australia/Brisbane")
R> x
[1] "2012-08-06 15:32:00 EST"
R> attr(x, "tzone")
[1] "Australia/Brisbane"
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. That is all I wanted to make sure of.